# Interface mismatch in dummy procedure: shape mismatch

Tags: arrays, fortran

I'm trying to implement a runge-kutta for a system of differential equations.
I'm having some trouble with the subroutine. I would like to make it a general code, to pass any system of equations to solve.

The main code of the program is:

```
program main

use ivp_odes

    implicit none

    double precision, allocatable :: t(:), y(:,:)
    double precision :: t0, tf, y0(2), h
    integer :: i

    t0 = 0d0
    tf = 0.5d0
    y0 = [0d0, 0d0]
    h = 0.1d0

    do i=lbound(t,1),ubound(t,1)
        print *, t(i), y(1,i), y(2,i)
    end do

contains

function myfun(t,y) result(dy)

    ! input variables
    double precision, intent(in) :: t, y(2)

    ! output variables
    double precision :: dy(2)

    dy(1) = -4*y(1) + 3*y(2) + 6
    dy(2) = -2.4*y(1) + 1.6*y(2) + 3.6
end function myfun

end program main
```

The `myfun` is an example function, which I have the analytical solution, so I can compare my implementation with the correct response of the system. This `myfun` function gets a variable `t` and a one-dimensional array of two elements `y` and returns its derivatives, so I can numerically integrate this.

The runge-kutta algorithm I implement in a separate module:

```
module ivp_odes
    implicit none
contains

subroutine rk4(t, y, f, t0, tf, y0, h)
    ! input variables
    double precision, intent(in) :: t0, tf, y0(1:)
    double precision, intent(in) :: h

    interface
        pure function f(t,y) result(dy)
            double precision, intent(in) :: t, y(:)
            double precision :: dy(size(y))
        end function
    end interface

    ! output variables
    double precision, allocatable :: t(:), y(:,:)

    ! auxiliar variables
    integer :: i, m, N
    double precision :: hh
    double precision, allocatable :: k1(:), k2(:), k3(:), k4(:)

    N = ceiling((tf-t0)/h)
    m = size(y0)

    allocate(k1(m),k2(m),k3(m),k4(m))

    if (.not. allocated(y)) then
        allocate(y(m,0:N))
    else
        deallocate(y)
        allocate(y(m,0:N))
    end if

    if (.not. allocated(t)) then
        allocate(t(0:N))
    else
        deallocate(t)
        allocate(t(0:N))
    end if

    t(0) = t0
    y(:,0) = y0

    do i=1,N
        k1(:) = h * f(t(i-1)      , y(:,i-1)        )
        k2(:) = h * f(t(i-1)+h/2 , y(:,i-1)+k1(:)/2)
        k3(:) = h * f(t(i-1)+h/2 , y(:,i-1)+k2(:)/2)
        k4(:) = h * f(t(i-1)+h   , y(:,i-1)+k3(:)  )

        y(:,i) = y(:,i-1) + (k1(:) + 2*k2(:) + 2*k3(:) + k4(:))/6
            t(i) = t(i-1) + h
        end do

        deallocate(k1,k2,k3,k4)

end subroutine rk4

end module ivp_odes
```

The idea of the `rk` subroutine is that `t` is the time vector (one dimensional array) and `y` is the response vector (two dimensional array, each row corresponds to a variable and each column corresponds to the value of the variable in the correspondent time).

I can't find a way to make it work, since I get errors when compiling the code, all related to the function `myfun` when calling the subroutine `rk` in the main code.

```
call rk4(t, y, myfun, t0, tf, y0, h)
                   1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure 'f' at (1): Shape mismatch in dimension 1 of function result
```

I tried to look for an answer to this problem, and already read this previously asked questions:

[Interface mismatch - higher order functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578987/interface-mismatch-higher-order-functions)

[Fortran array cannot be returned in function: not a DUMMY variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827878/fortran-array-cannot-be-returned-in-function-not-a-dummy-variable)

[Function in fortran, passing array in, receiving array out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170024/function-in-fortran-passing-array-in-receiving-array-out)

some of which already helped me solve some errors. However, what I'm trying to do is pretty much the same thing as the first question, but it simply doesn't work.

I'm using the GNU Fortran Compiler, and writing the code in Code::Blocks 16.01.
Can't find a way to solve it.

Here a few things I tried that hasn't worked:

- change the variable in the interface:

```
interface
    pure function f(t,yy) result(dy)
        double precision, intent(in) :: t, yy(:)
        double precision :: dy(size(y))
    end function
end interface
```

- not declare the result of the funciont in interface

```
interface
    pure function f(t,y)
        double precision, intent(in) :: t, y(:)
    end function
end interface
```

it produces the error:

```
    call rk4(t, y, myfun, t0, tf, y0, h)
                   1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure 'f' at (1): Type mismatch in function result (REAL(4)/REAL(8))
```

- I though I could use the procedure statement, but I think that to do that, I should declare my function myfun in the same module of the subroutine, right? But the idea to have a general code is that I don't need to open this module after finished, so anytime I want to use my rk4 integrator, I just call it, no noeed to specify the function in the same module.

Comment: Although [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30620604) is about assumed size rather than assumed shape, much of the detail holds here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `myfun` that you pass and the function that is expected `f` by the subroutine `rk4` are not of the same type:

- `f` is `pure`, while `myfun` is not.
- In `f`, `y` is deferred shape, while in `myfun` it is of explicit shape (with consequences to `dy`).

This is actually what the compiler is complaining about :)
Once you fix these issues, the code compiles fine.

Comment: Ok, code is compiling now.  I changed `myfun`, so it is `pure` now and  `y` has a deferred shape. But now I noticed another problem, In the do-loop inside the `rk` subroutine, the statement

`y(:,i) = y(:,i-1) + (k1(:) + 2*k2(:) + 2*k3(:) + k4(:))/6`

erases previous values of the array `y`. Why is this happening? Shouldn't it, in the i-th loop, change only the values of `y` in the i-th column?
Since Fortran has the element-wise operations already implemented, the code is clearer to read this and I think this runs faster than doing loops to assign each element.

Comment: @Thales That should probably go into a separate question :) But please, provide a little more information on this behavior. It is not clear to me what you mean by "erase".